# Is there a way to add variables to Kafka server.properties?

Tags: apache-kafka

I don't have any experience with Kafka yet and need to automate a task. Is there a way that I can use env variables in the configuration file?
To be more specific:

```
advertised.listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://<hostname>:29092
```

I'd like to extract and use the hostname from my env variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property files offer no variable interpolation

If you started Kafka via Docker processes, or write your own shell scripts which generate a property file prior to starting the broker, then you could inject values

Some examples include `confd`, `consul-template`, `dockerize`